# Ссылки из IE 9 - в TXT файл

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Здравствуйте, появился такой вопрос...

Как можно сделать, чтобы все ссылки, которые я пишу в IE 9 (Internet Explorer), записывались в мой txt файл (а лучше в dll файл)?

Если это не по теме, то глубоко извиняюсь, просто мне кажется, это тоже относится к php...

Comment: не совсем понятно, о каких "ссылках" речь... Уточните вопрос. Возможно, Вы имеете в виду адреса, по которым Вы переходите? Или, может быть, что-то другое??? Ссылки на текущей открытой странице?...

Answer (score 1):

Это не php. Варианты

- Ловить хэндл окна программно и мониторить нажатия
- Написать надстройку и выполнять аналогичные действия предыдущему пункту

---

p.s. Что вы имеете ввиду под записью в dll? Запись в файл ресурсов типа текста, а затем добавление в dll?

Comment: Ну что-то типо того:)
 Ладно спасибо и на этом...

Comment: Не за что, но других вариантов я не знаю.